# Write variable within value attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having difficulties in printing the array values into my value attributes:

below is my code:

```
$(".select").append("<option value="+ optionValues[i] +">"+ revList[i].innerHTML +"</option>");
```

My optionValues array consist of space for example:

[Autumn winter 2014, Winter fashion 2014..........]

However when I render out my element I get this :

```
<option value="Spring" summer="" 2014="">Spring/Summer 2014</option>
```

How do I format into something like this?

```
<option value="Spring summer 2014">Spring/Summer 2014</option>
```

Comment: Add quotation marks around the attribute value. You are currently producing `<option value=Spring summer 2014>`. If you want quotes, you have to add them. HTML 101.

Comment: You're missing literal quotes around the attribute values.

Comment: @MattBall - You can post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the value of `value` attribute within `quotes`, You can use *single* quote as out quote to make the option string and inner double quotes to wrap attribute values in *double* quotes.

```
$(".select").append('<option value="'+ optionValues[i] +'">'+ revList[i].innerHTML +'</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer these kind of things like following.

```
var select = $(".select").append('<option value="VALUE">TEXT</option>');
select = select.replace("VALUE",optionValues[i]).replace("TEXT",revList[i].innerHTML);
```

Using this way I don't really worry for quotes.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. You'd have to do this for every `option` in your `select`. Adding too much complexity just for the sake of not including some 's in your code

Comment: @jasonscript may it doesn't make sense to you. but I don't want to keep track that where I have started the quote and where to close, and all other concatenation stuff. So i use this method. I just told one way of doing it.